# Setting setDefaultSSLSocketFactory to enable SSL is causing Google map load to stop

Tags: android, https

I am facing an error. Once I make a call using SSL connection, by setting `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory` and a `TrustStore`, Google Map is not loading on my app anymore. If I change this to a `HTTP` call, Google Map loads without any issue.

Please let me know how to use `HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory` without affecting HTTP Calls. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Could you post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) from your code showing how you're making & using the HTTPS connection?

Comment: Thanks Dave for your response. I just found out that if I set the SSLSocket for each call and NOT set the Default, Google Maps loads fine. I don't know yet what about setDefaultSSLSocketFactory is causing Google Maps to not load but there it is. This is my code snippet to set the default Socket, that was not working -     HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(new NoSSLv3SocketFactory(sslContext.getSocketFactory()));
    URL url = new URL(Utils.TestServlet_SSL_URL());
    HttpsURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();